# if this cookie !== null then do this

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, jquery-cookie

Having a few issues with the plugin jquery-cookie by carhartl... just in terms of getting a stickyfooter to appear...

The idea is that there is a stickfooter that is always at the bottom of the page, if otherwise closed. Pretty simple.

So, the onclick of the cross fires two things: to hide the stickfooter div and append a session cookie.

Right now, it pops for a split second and then hides indefinitely. But the cookie hasn't been set yet.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    if (jQuery.cookie('stickyNewsClosed') === null) {
        jQuery('.stickyFooter').show();
    }
        if (jQuery.cookie('stickyNewsClosed') !== null) {
            jQuery('.stickyFooter').hide();
        }
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function closeSticky(){
    jQuery('.stickyFooter').hide();
    jQuery.cookie('stickyNewsClosed', 'yup', {
                path: '/'
            });
}
</script>
```

Perhaps use the .css() jquery method instead of .hide() / .show() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi please see here: http://plnkr.co/edit/yaXgcEsMuNaGu5dQJnL0?p=preview

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
console.log(jQuery.cookie('stickyNewsClosed'));
  if (jQuery.cookie('stickyNewsClosed') === undefined) {
    jQuery('.stickyFooter').show();
  }
 else if (jQuery.cookie('stickyNewsClosed') !== null) {
    jQuery('.stickyFooter').hide();
  }
});



function closeSticky() {

  jQuery('.stickyFooter').hide();
  jQuery.cookie('stickyNewsClosed', 'yup', {
    path: '/'
  });
}
```

Comment: Ah! An else if - brilliant!